# Pasar la información que obtengo de un archivo JavaScript a otro archivo

Tags: javascript

Tengo un proyecto que es una practica para métodos de pagos, lo que quiero hacer es del archivo `main.js` pasar lo obtenga del `input` y que el archivo `car.js` lo reciba y después pueda usar los datos pasados en cualquier momento, este es mi código:

```
import data from "./card.js"


 cityInput.addEventListener('input', () =>{
     city = cityInput.value
 })

 let upgrate

 submit.addEventListener('click', () =>{
     upgrate = new data(city)
     imprimir()
 })

export default function imprimir(){
    console.log(upgrate)
}
```

este es el codigo del archivo `main.js`, estuve intentando que cuando me pasaran algún valor en `cityInput`, cuando diera clic en *submit* poder guardarlo en la clase que importe del archivo `card.js`:

```
export default class data{
    constructor(names){
        this.names = names
    }
}

import imprimir from "./main.js"

imprimir()
```

y este es el codigo del archivo `card.js`, aquí lo que hice es que exporte la clase data para usarla en otro archivo y después poder usar el valor en el mismo archivo, pero no esta haciendo lo que esperaba que hiciera.

Answer (score 3):

Una opción en JavaScript, para transferir información entre archivos, es emplear `window`, que es de alcance global.

Por ejemplo, en tu primer archivo de JavaScript puedes declarar una variable global de esta forma:

```
window.upgrate = new data(city);
```

E inclusive una función global:

```
window.imprimir = function() { console.log(upgrate); };
```

Y en el segundo archivo de JavaScript puedes llamarlo, por ejemplo, de esta forma:

```
console.log(window.upgrate);
window.imprimir();
```

---

Ahora, si dispones de un fichero HTML desde donde importas tus ficheros de JavaScript, puedes emplear la solución propuesta en [esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file).

Se trata de incluir tu script contenedor de los datos a usar antes que el script que los usará:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="origen.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="destino.js"></script>
```